# how to call gradle init multiple times

Tags: maven, gradle

I use gradle init to convert maven to gradle project.
After call gradle init. I made some changes at pom.xml for new dependency. Then I called gradle init again, because I want to reflect new dependency to gradle project , but it failed due to build.gradle and settings.gradle already exist.

How to solve this problem? Is there any thing like gradle update ?
I think I am not only one with this problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems the init plugin does not come with options to clean the files should they exist: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_init_plugin.html

But what should be possible is to create your own "cleanupInit" task. in it delete the files you don't mind having re-generated and then add a statement to have `init.dependsOn cleanupInit` into your build.gradle

Since the init task is part of the migrating to gradle section I think the task might not be intended to be re-executed.